# Can't get number from another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code to calculate my grades average and I'm getting good average with my current grades, but I can't get good average with future grades. Sorry for not english in code :). This is my code:

```
def skaiciuojam_vidurki(*pazymiai):
    vidurkis = sum(pazymiai) / len(pazymiai)
    return vidurkis

def skaiciuojam_busima_vidurki(*busimi):
    bus_vidurkis = (vidurkiz + sum(busimi)) / (len(busimi) + len(vidurkiz))
    return bus_vidurkis

vidurkiz = skaiciuojam_vidurki(8, 9, 10, 1)
busymi = skaiciuojam_busima_vidurki(5, 10)

print("Jūsų dabartinis vidurkis: " + str(vidurkiz))
print("Jei gautum šiuos pažymius: " + str(busymi))
```

Comment: in your second function you don't have any variable `vidurkiz`

Comment: The problem is you're trying to get the length of a number, `vidurkiz`. You'd need to store your previous grades in a list and get the length of that to do what you want.